# Confidence Limits for normal vs rayleigh distributed random variables

Tags: confidence-interval, rayleigh-distribution

I have a device to measure a coordinate in one axis, the measurement error is $\Delta x$, which is specified that $3\sigma < thr$, where *thr* is say 1 nanometer, and the average is not specified.

Now I combine 2 such devices to measure an $(x,y)$ position and the measurement error is $r=\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}$.

I understand *r* is Rayleigh distributed.
How would I write the specification for $r$? I tried something like $\bar{x} + 3\sigma$, but the deviation is relatively high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are assuming (as is typical) that one-dimensional measurement errors are normally distributed, then the measurement error "radius" in two dimensions is Rayleigh distributed with parameter ($\sigma_r = $*thr*/3).

The Rayleigh quantile function gives the covering radius for any proportion of samples $p \in (0,1)$ as $\sigma_r \sqrt{-2 \ln (1-p)}$.  So, for example, setting *p*=50% we find that the median measurement error will be $\sigma_r 1.18 \approx 0.39 thr$.

[A $3 \sigma$ specification is giving the upper bound on 99.7% of samples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule). The Rayleigh formula says that, in two dimensions, 99.7% of error samples should be inside a radius of $\approx 1.14thr$.